# C: What is the type of &array_name?

Tags: c

What is the type of `&a` in the following code?

```
char a[100];
myfunc(&a)
```

Is this even valid code? `gcc -Wall` complains about missing prototype but will otherwise generate code as if `myfunc(a)` was written.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type of `&a` in that code is `char (*)[100]`, which means "pointer to array of 100 chars".

To correctly prototype `myfunc` to take that argument, you would do it like so:

```
void myfunc(char (*pa)[100]);
```

or the completely equivalent:

```
void myfunc(char pa[][100]);
```

**Addendum:**

In answer to the additional question in the comments:

1. Yes, you would use `(*pa)[0]` or `pa[0][0]` within `myfunc` to access the first element of the array.
2. No, `&a` (and thus `pa`) contain the address *of the array*.  They do *not* contain the address-of-an-address.  It should be obvious that the address of an array and the address of its first element are the same - the only difference is the type.  Thus `(void *)&a == (void *)a` is true, and `(void *)pa == (void *)pa[0]` is also true, even if this seems a little unintuitive.

Consider these two declarations:

```
char (*pa)[100];
char **ppc;
```

Now, even though `pa[0][0]` and `ppc[0][0]` are both of type `char`, the types of `pa` and `ppc` are *not* equivalent.  In the first case, the intermediate expression `pa[0]` has type `char [100]`, which then evaluates to a pointer to the first element in that array, of type `char *`.  In the second case, the intermediate expression `ppc[0]` is already a `char *`.

Comment: So in myfunc one would have to use (*pa)[0] or pa[0][0] to access the first element of the array? That means pa has the address of a memory location where the address of a[0] is stored.